# What, if any, are the disadvantages having a header file of header files?

Tags: c

I came onto a project that employs the method of using a header file `MyProject.h` that has all the headers of each .c file. Each .c file has their own header file that has `#include "MyProject.h"`, whatever libraries are needed, and any other declarations necessary for the file.

To me it seems redundant and somewhat unnatural, but it compiles and subsequently runs as expected. My thought is that the compiler would be doing way more work than necessary and is possibly over-bloating the .exe. What are the disadvantages, if any, to doing this?

A subsequent question I have is, say I included a library like Time.h in one file using the above example. Will the compiler only build Time.h once into the binary or for every file now because of MyProject.h? What about with structs, enums, etc...?

Comment: It may be convenient to include one file over several files, but it may so include unneeded files each time it is used.

Comment: @Jarod42 Are there disadvantages to that?

Comment: @Zola Precompiled headers are subject to implementation (compiler), even those who have the features (GCC, MSVC) set it off by default. The preprocessor will parse all included files by each .c / .cpp.

Comment: Building time is a non-issue. It is not something you should even consider when designing programs.

Comment: @Talaria you will notice longer (noticability depends on the complexity of the header files) compilation time. Preprocessing time becomes equal for each .c / .cpp, because they include the same set of header files despite each may only be using a few parts of it.

Comment: @Lundin It is when the build-time of a project closes in a couple of hours. :)

Comment: The major disadvantage of having such a collection of header files in one place, is that if you make a change in one header file, *all* source files have to be recompiled. It won't matter for small projects with only a few files and building takes just a couple of seconds, but for huge projects with several thousands of files and build times of maybe hours it's not a very good solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is at that very moment you should insist that you need a better computer.

Comment: You've included Time.h in one file, possibly polluting your namespace for all other files.  Perhaps some other file includes your file and your file includes that file and ... god knows what.  Include files are hell so keep it simple.  Don't #include anything in your header files.  #include them in your source files only and then for ease of use collapse them into one or two headers only.  Worried about "coupling"?  Don't.  Your code is reusable as you're working at the library, not individual source file level.

Comment: Build time is only a non-issue to those who do not test/debug software,  Empirically, I find that eliminating 99% of all household bugs is MUCH faster when using a language with modules instead of C++.  Also, it keep my caffeine consumption down if I can add debug/fix lines and rebuild in less time than it takes for my kettle to boil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have such a header file is poor practice and bad design. The problem is that it will create a tight coupling dependency between every single file of your project, even if they are completely unrelated.

Good program design is to create autonomous modules that only include the resources they are using. They should do this from their own h files, to document exactly which dependencies a particular module has.

Comment: What do you mean by tight coupling dependancy?

Comment: I disagree, except to add that it's perfectly fine to have tight coupling between modules in the same library.

Comment: @Robinson Tight coupling is something 100% bad, there is never a reason why you would strive for it. It makes the code harder to maintain and trouble-shoot, it makes the code more complex, and worst of all, any bugs in your code will escalate throughout the program, tearing down functionality which is completely unrelated to the bug. This is one of the main reasons why object-oriented design was invented.

Comment: Again, why?  I have a Font library that's emphatically very tightly coupled to FreeType 2.  I couldn't care less if it doesn't work with some other font rendering library X.  In the real world development is about making choices and for that library I've made a choice.

Comment: @Robinson Obviously, you need a coupling between one module and the resources that it uses. What I'm saying is that it should not have a tight coupling with completely unrelated modules. That is, if you update the font library and the update contains a bug, it shouldn't cause the coffee machine to suddenly stop working.

Comment: I see, yes, we agree.  I have found through experience that because, particularly in C/C++, you don't necessarily know what the library you're including will include, or what those includes will include, you rapidly lose track of what you're in fact coupled too.  Hence my "system" for making it explicit.

Comment: @Robinson You shouldn't be losing track though. When I design programs, before I write a single line of code, I draw up a "design chart" over all modules I expect the program to have and their dependencies. It doesn't necessarily have to be something fancy/formal (like UML), just as long as there's some sort of document which covers dependencies and heritage. You can then update this chart as the program is written. Ideally, there will be some coupling (!) between the specification, the chart, the code and the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

The main downside is increased build times. Every source file includes every header of the project, whether it needs it or not.

It's also conceptually unclean. A source file should include the headers it needs. It should be possible to search for a header's name to find the parts of the source code that uses these facilities. Minimizing unnecessary includes is evidence of a loosely coupled system. However, include-what-you-use is hard to enforce, because you cannot prevent transitive availability of facilities through headers in C.

It should not lead to increased executable size. Even if the headers contain code (which is rare in C, but common in C++), the linker should eliminate duplicates and remove unused code.

Comment: There are tools for minimizing unnecessary includes in language/environments like C# and Visual Studio.  In the absence of that kind of thing with C or C++ (though I'm sure there's a plug-in somewhere), don't manage your includes at the individual source file level.  That's far too fine grained.  Do it at the library level.

Comment: There's include-what-you-use, which is a standalone tool.

Comment: Unfortunately that advertises itself as "alpha quality" written specifically for the Google source tree, and "even for Google code, the tool still makes a lot of mistakes".  Apparently it's a hard problem to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Most of my libraries have one precompiled header containing external includes and one "main" header for each library that contains the precompiled header items + all the .h files for the library in question.  All of my .cpp files first include the precompiled header and then the main header.

That's it.  None of my other .h files have any includes in at all.  My .cpp files only include these two headers.  Other libraries that need to use the library will #include that same main header.

Doing this has greatly simplified header file headache/complexity issue for me though I would add that most of my libraries are relatively small in the grand scheme of things.  I don't know if this would work for a very large (monster) project.  Perhaps not.

The way this works is actually quite nice.  Others above, concerned about "coupling" want to minimise it, but if you don't include *any* headers at all you're 100% uncoupled, even from your dependencies.  If you want to reuse the class, use the library that contains it.

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers were clear enough, but.

The main disadvantage of "one big header file" is the problem with code reusability. For example, you've created some module as a part of your application. Let's say, this module implements API for some hardware. And then you want to make another application, which should use this module.

In this case you have to remember which header files you have to include to compile this module, or, if you just copy your previous "big header file", it requires a lot of unnecessary third party libraries and header files.

Nobody wants to spend a lot of time to make some module working. It's much better if you can use it right out-of-the-box, isn't it?